# App for iOS similar to Office Lens

Tags: ios, office, camera

[Office Lens](http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/17/office-lens-a-onenote-scanner-for-your-pocket/) is a Windows Phone app that does the following:

- Straightens images taken at an angle
- Auto-crops the important part of the image
- Shows what will be cropped before the image is taken
- Removes glare and shadows

[image: Office Lens Windows Phone app]

#### I would like an app that does the same, but for iOS. <sup><sup>(OneNote integration not needed)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before there even was [Office Lens](http://www.wpcentral.com/camscanner-vs-office-lens-windows-phone), the de-facto app for this sort of thing on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id388627783?mt=8) systems has been [**CamScanner**](http://www.intsig.com/en/CamScanner.html) for some time. It does exactly the sorts of things you're talking about here. There are quite a number of similar apps as well, but that is the one I've seen used by folks for this job.

[image: CamScanner screenshot]

Besides your requirements about auto-crop and perspective fixes, it also handles OCR and other document archival related tasks. These might actually make the app more cumbersome than useful to you, but there you have it.